# What do you call people who confront common belief, no matter if it is right or wrong?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

What do you call people who confront common belief, no matter if it is right or wrong? They do it for attention and confirmation from like-minded people?

Comment: Well a *demagogue* springs to mind: *a political leader who seeks support by appealing to popular desires and prejudices rather than by using rational argument.*

Comment: I don't understand what OP means by "people who confront common belief". Are we talking about [flat-earthers](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2016/jan/20/flat-earth-believers-youtube-videos-conspiracy-theorists) and [scientologists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientology), for example? Demagogues? Facists? Eugenicists? Populists? That last category in particular obviously ***appeal*** to "common belief", but I can't help suspecting they're the people *OP* has in mind.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. There are a wide variety of terms that could be employed in various scenarios; they might be a *muckraker*, or *antiestablishmentarian*, or simply an *instigator* who is *argumentative*. As such, your question is too vague to be properly, definitively answered. At the very least, describing real-life people with these qualities, and how you would use the word in a sentence, would help. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of how to ask good questions on this site.

Comment: "Dissenter", non-conformist" or "free spirit" may fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Contrarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrarian) - a person who takes up a contrary position, especially a position that is opposed to that of the majority, regardless of how unpopular it may be.

Comment: I agree with your answer for the first section of the question, but I'm not sure that a contrarian is looking for confirmation, certainly attention however, (+1).